# TokenService: Token expired message after a couple of minutes

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-1.5, microservices

We have a Java DXA project, which we run in a local Tomcat that's connecting to our Web 8 microservices (running in a VM). This works.

But after some time, I get errors in my local web app, claiming: Token Expired. When I restart the webapp (and Tomcat with it), it fails, because of the same reason.

Restarting discovery service (and all other services) and afterwards starting Tomcat back up doesn't help either.

Could someone please point to me what is causing this issue and how to solve/prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the VM's time was running slow, it was 5 minutes behind, so the token was already expired.